# Cannot process data in separate locations

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to load csv file to BigQuery from Google Cloud Storage by WebUI.
But sometimes occurs error.
Error message is "Cannot process data in separate locations".
What does it mean?
And how can I fix it?

Comment: The problem gone after few reruns of 'load'. But I'm wondering what was the reason.

Comment: That's right. But it occurs frequently, so I rerun to load many times. I want to know the reason.

Comment: This looks like a change in behaviour overnight and I suspect it's a bug/outage. I've opened a support ticket with Google but I don't think there's anything you can do right now to fix it, other than repeatedly trying to load the data. **EDIT** Had some feedback from Google. It possibly confirms that this is a slightly preemptive release of a feature that's coming.

Answer (score 1):

This was an unintended consequence of an update to the BigQuery service. We'll provide additional followup on this bug:
https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=270